# Problem with automatic start of windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have developed a windows service using visual studio 2008 and .net fw 3.5.1
I set the **StartType** of the service installer to *Automatic*. When I install the service in a Windows Server 2003 the service appears with the **StartType** set to *Automatic*. So far so good, but... when the server is restarted the service doesn't.
What might be happening?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Do you mean that the service doesn't start at all on Reboot, or that the Service is somehow set to Manual start type in the Service Properties dialog?

Comment: I mean the service doesn't start at all on reboot. It keeps saying is on Automatic. The service works fine when I started manually.

Comment: Can you install the service on a different OS and verify it works as expected? Also, as jro said, are there any entries in the event log that indicate the service encountered an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting 101: does the service run in manual mode?  It sounds as if the Service itself doesn't run.  Check your event log for entries.

If the Service can run in manual mode, only then do you look to the server for startup issues.

Edit: if the service can run in manual mode, consider the other controllable aspects of the service, such as the account under which the service executes (LocalSystem or some other account?)  Other things to look at are dependencies you service has on other parts of the server.  Does it require other services from the server to be enabled when it initializes?

Comment: The service works fine when I start it manually. I have run a lot of unit tests and the service fulfill them too.

Comment: Sorry!.. you were right the service is launching an error window in a different remote session of WS 2003... and I couldn't see it

Answer (score 0):

What does the service do? It might fail to start because the service itself doesn't run (as stated by jro). It could also be that your service isn't starting because it depends on another service which is not yet up and running during startup. If the latter is the case you should define a service dependency. That will delay the start of your service until the dependency has been started.

To analyse the problem, have a look at the event look. Hopefully you will find some more information there.

Comment: It might not be running on start also because it is depending on a user being interactively logged onto the system.